# My solution to $\int \frac{2x^2}{x^2+4}dx$

Tags: integration, solution-verification

$$\int \frac{2x^2}{x^2+4}dx$$

**Attempt.** I have actually done this integral but I'm wondering if what I did was correct as I have a different answer from WolframAlpha. Here it is: $$\int \frac{2x^2}{x^2+4}dx$$
$$2\int \frac{x^2}{x^2+4}dx$$ $$2\int 1dx -2\int\frac{4}{x^2+4}dx$$  $$2x-2\int\frac{4}{x^2+4}dx$$ and here, while I *now* realise that ther right integral is just $\tan(\frac{x}{2})$, I continued. Let $x=2\tan(\theta)$: $$2x -8\int\frac{1}{4\tan^2(\theta)+4}d\theta$$ $$2x -2\int\frac{1}{\tan^2(\theta)+1}d\theta$$ $$2x -2\int\frac{1}{\sec^2(\theta)}d\theta$$ $$2x -2\int\cos^2(\theta)d\theta$$ $$2x -2\int\frac{\cos(2\theta)+1}{2}d\theta$$ $$2x-\int\cos(2\theta)d\theta-\theta$$ $$2x-\int\cos(2\theta)d\theta-\theta$$ $$2x-\frac12 \sin(2\theta)-\theta$$ $$2x-\frac12 \sin(2\arctan(\frac{x}{2}))-\arctan(\frac{x}{2})$$

Again, I don't really care if there was a shortcut way to this, I just want to know if it is correct or not.

Comment: Shouldn’t it be $2x-2\int$ rather than $2x+2\int?$ $$\frac{x^2}{x^2+4}=1-\frac{4}{x^2+4}$$

Comment: Make things simple. Every well-bred young people should know b heart the $$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^2+a^2}=\frac1a\arctan\frac xa.$$

Comment: In addition to mistake pointed out by @ThomasAndrews, $x = 2\tan\theta \implies dx = 2 \sec^2\theta \ d\theta$. Where did you use that?

Comment: @MathLover: you also write $\mathrm dx =2(1+\tan^2\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta$.

Comment: If you want to know if your answer is right, derive it to see if the derivative is the function you started out with. Sometimes, if you don't have the right answer, you can catch your error when comparing the function and the derivative of its faulty integral.

Comment: oh okay thanks @MathLover and Thomas Andrews , now I see the error. Everything is good now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to integrate a rational function—a quotient of polynomials. If the degree of the numerator is greater than or equal to the degree of the denominator, then use polynomial long division to turn the improper fraction into a proper fraction. This will make life much easier. Here,
$$
\frac{2x^2}{x^2+4}=2-\frac{8}{4+x^2} \, .
$$
Now the problem has been reduced to evaluating
$$
\int\frac{dx}{4+x^2} \, .
$$
We can proceed in the following way:
$$
\int\frac{dx}{4+x^2} = \frac{1}{4}\int\frac{dx}{1+\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2} \, .
$$
By the chain rule,
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\arctan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{2} \tag{*}\label{*} \, ,
$$
and so
$$
\int\frac{dx}{4+x^2}=\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{dx}{1+\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2}=\frac{1}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+C \, .
$$
The overall integral therefore equals
$$
\int 2-\frac{8}{4+x^2} \, dx = 2x -4\arctan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) + C \, .
$$
The substitution you made is perfectly valid, but it is easier to directly apply the chain rule in reverse as I did in $\eqref{*}$. Substitutions should be reserved for more complicated integrals where it is not immediately clear how you can apply the chain rule in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

When you went from $\displaystyle-2\int{4\over x^2+4}\,dx$ to $\displaystyle-8\int{1\over4\tan^2(\theta)+4}\,d\theta$ using the substitution $x=2\tan(\theta)$, it looks like you simply replaced $dx$ with $d\theta$. The correct relationship is $dx=2\sec^2(\theta)d\theta$. The secant squared (which cancels the secant squared in the denominator) makes a world of difference.